# Viewing all albums sorted by year in Apple Music

Tags: itunes, music

Is there a way to see an artist's albums by year in Apple Music? I've searched around and I can't even see a page where all an artist's albums are listed, let alone a chronological listing.

For example, go into Apple Music and search for "They Might Be Giants". According to Wikipedia they have [19 studio albums from 1986 to present](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/They_Might_Be_Giants#/Discography), but if you select "Albums >" from their Apple Music page you don't see all their albums (even the ones listed elsewhere on Apple Music). (And actually most of what you see are not actually albums, but singles, which just confuses things further).

Edit: It's the same with David Bowie, The Smiths, and just about anyone else I've checked. Sigh :(

I hate to say it, but unless I'm missing something, the Zune software was doing this better 10 years ago :(